# Python clicker application, not performing actions after focusing on the window

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to create a clicker application using Python. In my code, I'm using the pygetwindow library to focus on a specific window and the pyautogui library to perform mouse clicks. However, after focusing on the window, the program doesn't perform any actions, and the mouse clicks don't happen.

The steps I need to perform are as follows:

```
Find and focus on the target window using the pygetwindow library.
Perform mouse clicks at specific coordinates to input data.
```

However, after focusing on the window, the mouse clicks are not being executed. Here's my code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import pygetwindow as gw

def verileri_gir(input_dosya, hedef_pencere_adi):
    time.sleep(1)
    with open(input_dosya, 'r') as dosya:
        veriler = dosya.readlines()

    for veri in veriler:
        veri = veri.strip()
        id, sifre = veri.split(":")  # ID ve şifreyi ayır

        # Giriş kutusu koordinatlarını belirle (örneğin)
        id_koordinat = (725, 420)
        sifre_koordinat = (725, 455)

        # Hedef pencereyi bul ve odaklan
 
        # ID'yi gir
        tikla_ve_kopyala(id_koordinat, id)
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Bekleme süresi

        # Şifreyi gir
        tikla_ve_kopyala(sifre_koordinat, sifre)
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Bekleme süresi

        # Giriş yap düğmesine tıkla (örneğin)
        giris_dugme_koordinat = (775, 565)
        tikla(giris_dugme_koordinat)
        
         # Pencereye yanıt vermesini bekleyin
        

def tikla_ve_kopyala(koordinat, metin):
    tikla(koordinat)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')  # Metini seç
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')  # Metini kopyala
    pyautogui.typewrite(metin)  # Metini yapıştır

def tikla(koordinat):
    pyautogui.click(koordinat)  # Belirtilen koordinata tıkla

def hedef_pencereyi_odakla(pencere_adi):
    hedef_pencere = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(pencere_adi)
    if len(hedef_pencere) > 0:
        hedef_pencere[0].activate()
    return hedef_pencere[0] if len(hedef_pencere) > 0 else None

# Verileri girmek için örnek kullanım
input_dosya = 'hesap.txt'  # İçindeki verilerin olduğu dosya
hedef_pencere_adi = 'InstaFly'  # Hedef programın pencere adı
verileri_gir(input_dosya, hedef_pencere_adi)
```

In my Python code, I tried to create a clicker application using the pygetwindow and pyautogui libraries. The specific steps I followed were as follows:

```
Read input data from a file.
Strip and split the data to separate the ID and password.
Determine the coordinates of the input boxes.
Find and focus on the target window using the pygetwindow library.
Perform mouse clicks at the specified coordinates to input the ID and password.
Click the login button.
Wait for the window to respond.
```

I expected that after focusing on the window, the program would successfully perform the mouse clicks at the specified coordinates to input the ID and password. However, the actual result was that the program successfully focused on the window, but it did not perform any actions afterward. The mouse clicks were not executed, and the input was not entered into the respective fields.

I'm seeking assistance to understand why the program is not performing the desired actions after focusing on the window.